# JPA select values from dynamicallay created table

Tags: jpa

I have some dynamically created tables(using native queries). So I do not have the names in my entity but stored in a db table. Now I want to retrieve datas from each. I want to use only JPA.

Answer (score 0):

To use JPA you must have Entity that maps on to any table that you want to access. If you don't have that then JPA is not for you, and just use JDBC. Can't get simpler.

Comment: thanks Neil. I created a simple entity with all the objects that i need to map for that dynamic table and hence I was able to populate the datas. but there was a by-product, an unused, dummy table in my database. Except that, everything is fine. Is there any idea not to create that table?